# trigger to update parent record field from child

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement where i need to update a field on Account object everytime a related case is closed.
The Field "Closed Cases" is a number field on Account object. Everytime, I close a case, this field should be incremented by 1.
I wrote a trigger but it's showing NULL Pointer Exception.
Please let me know if you see any issues here:

```
public class caseTriggerHandler {
    public static void autoFillNoOfContacts(List<Case> caseList, map<id, Case> oldCase){
        Set<ID> AccIDs= New Set<ID>();
        List<Account> accsToUpdate = New List<Account>();
        
        for (Case cs:caseList){
            if(cs.status=='closed' && oldCase.get(cs.Id).status<>'closed'){
                AccIDs.add(cs.AccountId);
            }
        }
                       
        Decimal noOfCases= 0;
        for(Account acc: [SELECT ID, Closed_Cases__c, (SELECT Id,Status FROM Cases) FROM Account WHERE Id IN:AccIDs]){
            noOfCases+=noOfCases;
            acc.Closed_Cases__c+=noOfCases;
            accsToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
        update accsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the below line .

```
acc.Closed_Cases__c+=noOfCases;
```

If the value of Closed_Cases__c field is null then you are adding 1 to the null which gives null pointer exception. Instead of that you can make the default value of the field to 0 or replace that line with the below line.

```
      if(acc.Closed_Cases__c!=null){
        acc.Closed_Cases__c+=noOfCases;
        }
        acc.Closed_Cases__c=1;
```

Which means if the value is null and we are closing the case this will populate to 1 if it is not null then it will increment by 1.

Even the above code may not work as expected because the trigger should work for the existing closed cases as well. so the logic should be counting the number of closed cases and populating the value as below.

```
if(AccIDs != null && AccIDs.size() > 0){
        List<Account> lstAccount = [select id, Closed_Cases__c , (select id from Cases where status = 'Closed') from Account where id in: AccIDs];
        if(lstAccount.size() > 0){
            for(Account acc: lstAccount){
                acc.Closed_Cases__c  = acc.Cases.size();
            }
            
            update lstAccount;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Technically* the original code is adding `0` to `acc.Closed_Cases__c` and not `1` - although that may be what the OP is intending to do.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has a multitude of flaws, noOfCases counting nothing, as well as an inefficient query, plus not including things like the account changing.

You can just do this:

```
public static void autoFillNoOfContacts(List<Case> caseList, map<id, Case> oldCase){
  Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
  if(caseList != null) { 
    for(Case record: caseList) {
      accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, Closed_Cases__c=0));
    }
  }
  if(oldCase != null) {
    for(Case record: oldCase.values()) {
      accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, Closed_Cases__c=0));
    }
  }
  accounts.remove(null); // Don't count null values
  for(AggregateResult result: [
     SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, AccountId AccountId 
     FROM Case 
     WHERE IsClosed = TRUE AND AccountId = :accounts.keySet()]) {
    accounts.get((Id)result.get('AccountId')).Closed_Cases__c = (Integer)result.get('sum');
  }
  update accounts.values();
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on sfdcfox's statement, "noOfCases [is] counting nothing", your `noOfCases` is counting nothing and doing no work: You initialize its value to `0`, then you do nothing with it until the line `noOfCases += noOfCases` which translates to `0 += 0` so its value is still `0`. Your next line then adds `noOfCases` which is `0` to `acc.Closed_Cases__c`, so that value would never change. Then you do nothing else with `noOfCases`, so its value will *always* be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

From the simple requirement of incrementing the case count I would use the ternary operator, which the short form of if then else + variable assignment.

By this you have the a one liner. See below

```
public static void autoFillNoOfContacts(List<Case> caseList, map<id, Case> oldCase){
    Set<ID> AccIDs= New Set<ID>();
    List<Account> accsToUpdate = New List<Account>();   
    for (Case cs:caseList){
        if(cs.status=='closed' && oldCase.get(cs.Id).status<>'closed'){
           AccIDs.add(cs.AccountId);
        }
    }                   
    for(Account acc: [SELECT ID, Closed_Cases__c, (SELECT Id,Status FROM Cases) FROM Account WHERE Id IN:AccIDs]){
        acc.Closed_Cases__c = acc.Closed_Cases__c == null ? 1 : acc.Closed_Cases__C +1;
        accsToUpdate.add(acc);
    }
    update accsToUpdate;
}
```